# C# simple grid filling algorithm

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find an efficient way to fill a gird (2 arrays) with numbers representing the area the cell in the grid occupies. For example:

The numbers correlates to the root area. The question is how can I randomly fill the matrix with these values that correlates to the root area

```
// Grid could look something like this 
// 22333
// 22333
// 11333
// or
// 33311
// 33322
// 33322
// What i have currently

int numRows = 4;
int numColums = 5;
int cellSize = Random.Range(0,4);

for (int iRow = 0; iRow < numRows; iRow++) {

    for (int iCol = 0; iCol <numColums ; iCol++) {

        // Fill value
        test.gridData.rows[iRow].colum[iCol] = cellSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this another way? Your example of what it should look like makes no sense when compared to what you described in the question.

Comment: It is a bit unclear how in your example the cell content relates to the number of cells of that particular value. `1` is contained in 2 cells, `2` is contained in `4` cells and `3` is contained in 9 cells.

Comment: I assume the number correlates to the root of the area (i.e 3 for a 3x3 area).  But what comes first? are you given the number 3 and then need to fill a 3x3 area or do you have the area and need to fill the value of each cell to 3?

Comment: Correct the number correlates to the root area. The question is how can I randomly fill the matrix with these values that correlates to the root area.

Comment: Why does 1 appear twice?  Shouldn't it appear only once (1 x 1)?

Comment: 1 occupies a 1x1 .. so two 1x1 are next to eachother

Comment: Sorry to close this but I couldn't find any question here. If you want, you could rephrase your question (as edit of your post) and it will be marked for re-open.

Answer (score 0):

```
int numRows = 4;
int numColums = 5;
int cellSize = Random.Range(0,4);

for (int iRow = 0; iRow < numRows; iRow++) {
    for (int iCol = 0; iCol <numColums ; iCol++) {
        // HERE
        test.gridData[iRow][iCol].MyVal= val;
    }
}
```

Assuming your actual code reflects the code in your question, the `MyVal` property of your `Test` matrix at position `[row][column]` is now equal to the value of `cellSize`.

You can access individual elements of a 2D array as such:

Assuming your grid is:

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 1 2 3 4
2 1 2 3 4
3 1 2 3 4
```

You can access individual cells using something like `test.GridData[2][4]` which will give you (assuming the above grid):

the value at `row[2]` => `2`

```
    ⬇
0 1 2 3 4
1 1 2 3 4
2 1 2 3 4
3 1 2 3 4
```

and `column[4]` => 4:

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 1 2 3 4
2 1 2 3 4
3 1 2 3 4 ⬅
```

Comment: Hey Jay thanks for the reply. My question was more to do with how can I fill the arrays with the correct values.